# for loop to create Image(),but get the width and height failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't get some image's `width` and `height`, but some on some others I can via `Image.width` and `Image.height`. Why some can and some can't?

```
var i = 0;
var len = imgitem.length;
for( i = 0; i < len ; i++){
    imgSrc = imgitem[i].url;

    imgObj = new Image();
    imgObj.src = imgSrc;
    imgObj.onload = function(){
        console.log(imgObj.width);
        imgObjW = imgObj.width;
        imgObjH = imgObj.height;
    };

    /*限制最大height*/
    if(imgObjH / imgObjW >= 1.5){
    ......
```

some HTML element

```
<div class="sfc-pic-play-item" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"><div class="sfc-pic-play-item-wrap"><div class="c-img c-img-s" style="background:none"><img src="http://a.jpg" class="sfc-pic-play-center"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: this line `if(imgObjH / imgObjW >= 1.5){` has to be executed inside the `onload`-handler

Comment: Some can and some won't beacause some will get load and some won't till uh reach if() condition place this inside onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your condition has to be inside the onload-handler, or it may/will be executed before the image is loaded.

And as Jonas w pointed out, there will also be a problem with imgObj not referencing the right object at the time.

```
imgitem.forEach(function(item){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = item.url;
    img.onload = function(){
        var w = img.width, 
            h = img.height;

        console.log(item, img, w, h);

        if(h/w >= 1.5){
                //...
        }
    }
});
```

If this still throws some error, we need to see how you adapted that to your code

Comment: YES! Get it, maybe relation to the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Simple async + for loop problem:

```
for(i = 0; i < len ; i++){
(function(){
   var imgSrc = imgitem[i].url;
   var imgObj = new Image();
   imgObj.src = imgSrc; 
   imgObj.onload = function(){ 
     console.log(imgObj.width);
      imgObjW = imgObj.width; 
     imgObjH = imgObj.height; 
     /*限制最大height*/ 
     if(imgObjH / imgObjW >= 1.5){ ......}
   };
   //imgObjH is 0 as it isnt loaded yet
 })();
 }
```

As imageObj refers to the latest object, your onload handler wouldnt do what you expect. Use the upper code to fix or use `this` instead of imageObj in your onload. Also the if looks a bit missplaced there...

Comment: If he solves his timing problem, then there is no scoping problem. Although polluting the global namespace with variables __is__ ugly.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, edited. But the timing problem not only consists of the onload/if but also on the onload in a for loop

Comment: I use this can't solve the problem and have Syntax error。

Comment: @Chang1ng `function` not `Function`

Comment: The problem also exist.   0.0